# Python - using variable instead of direct file name

Tags: python, zip

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
# Create a ZipFile Object and load sample.zip in it
with ZipFile('sampleDir.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
   # Extract all the contents of zip file in current directory
   zipObj.extractall()
```

I want to use a variable instead of sampleDir.zip
so that when i place the above code inside for loop that will change the file name each time.

Comment: OK. Where will you get the file names from? User `input`? A `list`?

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking for our permission?

Comment: @doctorlove  From the folder where all zip files are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
# Create a ZipFile Object and load sample.zip in it
var = 'sampleDir.zip'
with ZipFile(var, 'r') as zipObj:
   # Extract all the contents of zip file in current directory
   zipObj.extractall()
```

Comment: How do i replace "\\\\" to "\" ?  Can some one help

Comment: Your welcome! Accept the answer and upvote for future reference please .

Comment: Something like this would work: x.replace("\\\\","\")

Comment: @DharwinM I suspect the backslashes is a new question